# list style is not changing. still displaying the dot at the beginning

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner. Trying to style the list so no dot/dash shows in front of the list item but it is still showing the dot. How do you remove the dot/dash from the list items?

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <p> Item One </p>
   </li>

   <li>
     <p> Item Two </p>
   </li>

</ul>
```

Is there a css style option to remove the dot?
my list shows like this:

```
 - Item One

 - Item Two
```

How to remove the dash? or dot or square ?

Comment: `ul {list-style-type: none}`

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you add it as an answer so I could award you the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
<ul class="item-list">
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
</ul>

// In this css file add bellow

ul.item-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: why all answers are showing -1 except yours? I'm trying to understand how stackoverflow works but I can't find anything online regarding those numbers 1 and -1?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this. It works fairly well in CSS.

```
ul li{
list-style = none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hello i think i can help you

```
 <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    </style>
```

You can try it by running this code with the `<style>...</style>` tag.

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) -> You can get help from this link for details.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use an ID selector instead of class. Here is an example of how you can do that. https://www.campsitecoders.com/LEARN/CSS3/how-to-style-bulletlists.html